# How to Disable the labels on QwtSlider in Qt and show only ticks just like QSlider?

Tags: qt, slider, label, qwt

I am using a QwtSlider that has maximum value of 4294967295 (unsigned int 4bytes). Now I want only to show tick marks but not labels as the labels are displayed in exponential form. How to show only tick marks and also calculate the number of ticks(like tick Intervals in QSlider) to show based on the user desired number?

I have tried overriding label function in `QwtAbstractScale` class to return empty string, then create an instance of my class of `QwtAbstractScale` class type, typecast to `QwtScaleDraw` and using this in QwtSlider `setScaleDraw` function.

I expect the slider to look like QSlider with no labels and customisations  like number of ticks, ticks on both sides etc.

Solution : I achieved to show only default ticks without labels by

```
QwtScaleDraw* scaledraw = new QwtScaleDraw();
scaledraw->enableComponent(QwtAbstractScaleDraw::Labels, false);
```

But I want to customize the number of ticks of the QwtSlider based on the user entered value. How to achieve this?

Comment: Can you show what you have already worked on so far?

Comment: I have edited with the answer. But I want to customize number of slider ticks in qwtslider ...Can u please guide me how to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Using QwtAbstractScale::setScale( const QwtScaleDiv & ) you have complete control over all ticks.

When using setScale( const QwtInterval & ) the ticks will be calculated by a QwtScaleEngine. The existing scale engines have a couple of parameters that have an effect on the implemented algo, but of course you can also implement and assign your own type of scale engine.